# Google maps not obtaining current position

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to center the map on my current position, but it is not working.

I have:
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();

and the pin is shown correctly in my current position, but I am not able to animate/center de map to that point.

What I have is:

```
(...)
GeoPoint g = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();

if (g != null)
{
    //it never comes to this part
mapController.animateTo(g);
mapController.setZoom(17);
}
```

but `g` is always null.}
I have tried changing the IF into a WHILE (and updating g of course) para its and infinite loop.

Should I get my current position some other way?

In my manifest I have the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

I am testing in a Nexus One 2.3.6

Any help is appreciated

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html#googlemaps

Answer (score 0):

what i would suggest is Construct GeoPoint from Lat and Lon.

Try this approach.

```
LocationManager lm;
GeoPoint gp;        

lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location lastKnownLoc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (lastKnownLoc != null){
  int longTemp = (int)(lastKnownLoc.getLongitude()* 1000000);
  int latTemp = (int)(lastKnownLoc.getLatitude() * 1000000);
  gp =  new GeoPoint(latTemp, longTemp);
}
```